# Merge 2 objects with similar prop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to merge 2 objects where there's a similar prop on both and I want to have all props together:

```
let obj1 = {'foo': 'bar', 'far': {'tst': 1}}

let obj2 = {'far': {'other': 'token'}}

Object.assign({},obj1, obj2);

// Outputs: {"foo":"bar","far":{"other":"token"}}

// Desired output: {"foo":"bar","far":{'tst': 1, "other":"token"}}
```

Do I need to use the spread operator in some way?

Comment: @bigless it is a duplicate. Google didn't do me grace on this one. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

Do you try it?

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = hege.concat(stale);
```

Comment: Array concatenation doesn't have anything to do with this question.

Comment: My fault! I dont pay attention in this detail.

Comment: Here is a thread about the solution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: I'd recommend you update your answer, or just delete it (there's a link next to Edit).

Comment: @novaretti.jon sorry, that's also not the answer.. I have found the answer. It doesn't exists natively but with libraries.